# Simple/Quick way to show/hide rows of an extremely large table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, linq-to-sql, html-table

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have an extremely large list of items. Let's say it's around 130,000 items long. Each item is a string, something along the lines of 'almond antique azure green firebrick'.

Right now, I'm just putting each item as a single cell in a single row of a table. It would be nice to only display items starting with a, or starting with b, and so on. I'm having a few problems with the js I'm writing to do this, but the biggest one is speed - doing ANYTHING on a table consisting of this many items is really slow. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

If the answer is no, then it's fine - this is an extra credit assignment for a databases class, and this component is on reporting. This particular dataset came from a DB table with 6 million items, so there's nothing that can really be done to reduce the size.

EDIT: Here's some more information on the problem. I am creating this HTML page through a C# program. The program uses LINQ2SQL to query this massive database, gets the results, and outputs it into an HTML file. This isn't going to be a website, no data is going to be coming from a server; this is a static HTML page, viewable in a browser. I could have implemented this as a csv if I wanted, but  I think it looks nicer as a churched-up HTML file.

The type of data that I'm loading is this: "For each region, find all products that were not sold in the first half of 1993". So, with about 200,000 products, each region typically only sold about 70k. This means that there are 130k unsold products, and we have to list all of them for each region. I do have a separate HTML file for each region, but I can't think of any way to reduce the data further than that.

Further Edit: Thanks for everybody's suggestions. The short answer to this question, I guess, is "no; this is going to be slow". As one commenter said, lists of 100k+ items don't belong in HTML documents. I was going above and beyond the scope of my homework anyway by even doing this much, so I'll just let it rest.

Comment: Do you mean grouping each letter under its own <tbody> tag? No, I haven't tried that.

Comment: must the data be rendered into one table~ could you put the data into multiple identically styled table?

Comment: you need to implement lazy loading and a custom data view control

Comment: Eh...I can't really think of any way to split the data up logically. I'll post more info on what's going in in an edit, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could render descriptive classes onto the `<tr>`s and/or `<td>`s server-side, then you could just change the class of the parent table, and the browser would take care of re-rendering the table following the appropriate CSS.

```
table.just_a td,
table.just_bipeds td {
    display:none;
}

table.just_a td.a,
table.just_bidpeds td.biped {
    display:inherit;
}

<table class="" id="theTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="a quadraped">Anteater</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="z quadraped">Zebra</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="h biped">Human</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('thTable').className='just_a'" value="Just A" />
```

Comment: try doing this with 130k records. This isn't going to be any faster.

Comment: @Raynos why not? to clarify, my answer is based on the ability to render the table this way in the first place (server side)

Comment: I guess it's possible, but the search possibilities are limited to what you hardcoded on the server

Comment: @Raynos Agreed. But I don't see any reason to do _complicated_ searches client side. Simple categorical searches can be pre-optimized in this way~

Comment: For the scope of this homework assignment, I ended up deciding that this wasn't worth my time. The formatting of this report is a tiny piece...the next section on data mining is going to take me far longer, so I just said "screw it". Had I implemented it, however, I would have gone this way. =)

Answer (score 1):

No matter what it's going to be slow, sorry.  Unless you're running on your web browser on a Blade server or something ;-)

However, there is one trick that will legitimately speed up things: instead of setting the display property of the rows to "none", set their class to "nodisplay", and define a css rule:

```
.nodisplay { display:none }
```

Now you might think, what's the difference, but in fact (as PPK of quirksmode.org once proved with benchmarks) browsers are faster at switching classes with associated style changes than they are at making direct style changes to elements.

Can't say that it will make changing your insanely huge table *fast*, but it should make it *faster*.

Comment: P.S. Everyone else is right though: instead of putting all of the data in as rows in the HTML, you really should keep it all in the Javascript layer and only create rows for what you need (or better yet, if you can just keep it in the DB and query/re-query via AJAX as needed).  Your performance will be much better.

Comment: You're absolutely right - however, the scope of this HW assignment was to simply generate a report. The professor did not think about the implications of generating reports on such a massive dataset, but still - I'd rather spend my time on the k-means clustering section than on formatting what I've already spent too much time on. ;) Thank you for your suggestions, though - definitely something to think about for the future.

Answer (score 0):

The key to performance when inserting lots of data into the website is to reduce the number of refreshes of the page.  This can be done by trying to add all the data at once by concatting all the html into a string and inserting only once.

For example:

```
var html = "<table>";

for (var i = 0; i < listOfData.length; i++)
{
  html += "<tr><td>" + listOfData[i] + "</td></tr>";
}
html += "</table>";

// Insert it
$("body").html(html);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @EvanMoran -1 this is a myth. DOM manipulation & String manipulation are just as expensive.

Comment: @Raynos: you couldn't be more wrong. Every time the DOM is manipulated the browser has to re-render and repaint the page which is the single most expensive task a browser can perform. Especially when what you are manipulating is a table which auto computes width and height based on content in it. If you really believe what you wrote, do a simple test where you insert 1000 rows into a table with single appends and do it with a single append, you eyes will open ;)

Comment: @MartinJespersen Did you honestly think I didn't [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/domvsstring/4) this? It's a myth. There the exact same speed. On the other hand, dropping the jQuery abstraction and using the DOM directly, there you can gain a speed boost.

Comment: You're both right :-)  Using strings is not any faster than direct manipulation, BUT doing a single operation is faster than doing a whole bunch of small ones.  So if you compare some sort of loop that appends an element in each iteration, vs. a similar loop that instead concatenates a string and then sets that string as the new HTML, it will be faster (not because it was done via string manipulation, but because you made one DOM change vs. a whole bunch).

Comment: @Raynos: Well yes, and you just proved me right, seeinga s you only tested it in chrome. Try to test it in the browsers most people on the net use, like ie7 (you test won't even run in this), ie8 and firefox - forget chrome it's useless for stuff like this ;) As you will see in these browsers the difference in performance is very significant.

Comment: @Machineghost That's exactly what the benchmark does. @MartinJespersen If your not using chrome its not my fault the code is slow

Comment: It's definitely not a myth. Every time a change is made to the dom that impacts the layout of the page the browser has to recalculate the position and size of all elements. This process is called reflow and is very expensive. There is a detailed article and video about it here: http://code.google.com/speed/articles/reflow.html. I actually blogged about my experience once as well: http://blog.thinklinkr.com/post/598225347/browser-reflow-javascript-performance-in-action.

Answer (score 0):

I hate homework that doesn't make any sense! The right answer is, this is the wrong way to do this. You shouldn't try to display 100K+ (or even 10K..) items on a single HTML page, ever. But if the question is "how best to do something the wrong way," then I would do the following to break it down to a manageable size for display, while still keeping everything in a single client page

1) Render the data not as HTML, but as a Javascript array sorted alphabetically

2) Create a simple menu in HTML/javascript that lets the user select just the first letter

3) Using JS again render the table using data from the array you constructed before. To avoid time-consuming selections from that array, you could keep a separate index of the first element for each letter of the alphabet.

A JS array with 100K items is still going to be perceptibly slow, I would imagine, but probably a lot slower than trying to render it all at once.

You could further use something to create paging if that was what you wanted, just using all the data from your array.

Comment: You want to keep the data in the database and use highly optimised queries on it. If you want to do anything fast with 100k+ records then do it using SQL

Comment: Well, of course. That's why I said "this doesn't make any sense" and this is "how best to do something the wrong way." It's a homework question, he asked how to do something in a specific way, not for suggestions on how to approach a general problem.

Answer (score -1):

Stick to the csv, 130k list items do not belong in a html page.